# Generating xml using python dynamically

Tags: python, xml

createxml.py

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

var3 = raw_input("Enter the root Element: \n")
root = ET.Element(var3)

no_of_rows1=input("Enter the number of sub root for XML files: - \n")

def printme():
    var4 = raw_input("Enter the sub root Element: \n")
    doc = ET.SubElement(root, var4)
    no_of_rows=input("Enter the number of Element for XML files: - \n")
   #print no_of_rows
    for num in range(0, no_of_rows):
         print num
         var = raw_input("Enter Element: - \n")
         var1 = raw_input("Enter Data: - \n")

         ET.SubElement(doc, var).text =var1
    return;
for num in range(0, no_of_rows1):    
    printme()

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
file = raw_input("Enter File Name: - \n")
tree.write(file)

ET.ElementTree(root).write(file, encoding="utf-8",    xml_declaration=True)         
print "Xml file Created..!!"
```

Above one is script for create xml dynamically. But had one problem that showing error while writing to xml file. Whats the wrong with code? Wherever i am giving input from console its saying nameError.

Below is the output that i am gettin

```
Enter the root Element: 
names
Enter the number of sub root for XML files: - 
2
Enter the sub root Element: 
name1
Enter the number of Element for XML files: - 
2
0
Enter Element: - 
fname
Enter Data: - 
mad
1
Enter Element: - 
lname
Enter Data: - 
deck
Enter the sub root Element: 
name2
Enter the number of Element for XML files: - 
2
0
Enter Element: - 
fname
Enter Data: - 
Don
1
Enter Element: - 
lname
Enter Data: - 
brad
Enter File Name: - 
new.xml

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cosmitude10/neon/createxmlpython/writexml.py", line 27, in    <module>
ET.ElementTree(root).write(file, encoding="utf-8",  xml_declaration=True)         
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 812, in write
write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='%s'?>\n" % encoding)
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'
```

Comment: could you paste here the error that is displayed? I have tested your code and it works fine (although I have to indent the code properly).

Comment: "NameError: name 'go' is not defined" writting to an xml file. its showing and getting warning as "Assignment to reserved built-in symbol: file
"

Comment: `go` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted @mad Also avoid using the name `file` as it is a builtin keyword.

Comment: After changing file name then also showing that NameError.

Comment: go is nothing but xml file name

Comment: @mad:  please repaste your code properly formatted.  indentation matters a lot in python.

Comment: Repasted the code properly

Comment: Could you provide us with your python version? Also, could you paste or edit the question with all the console output? From your `python createxml.py`, with all the inputs introduced to the error thrown. So that we can reproduce it on our side.

Comment: python version is 2.7